# How to replace AppInviteApi .getInvitation(...) by FirebaseAppInvite.getInvitation(...)?

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services, google-app-invites

I upgrade today google play service library to the last and now i have such error like :

> warning: [deprecation] getInvitation(GoogleApiClient,Activity,boolean)
>   in AppInviteApi has been deprecated

when i read the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/android/gms/appinvite/AppInviteApi) they say

> This interface was deprecated. getInstance() is the main entry point
>   for accessing Dynamic Link data and use
>   getInvitation(com.google.firebase.dynamiclinks.PendingDynamicLinkData)
>   for getting AppInvites data from the Dynamic Link data.

But i don't understand how i can convert my previous code :

```
AppInvite.AppInviteApi.getInvitation(mGoogleApiClient, mActivity, mAutoLaunchDeepLink)
  .setResultCallback(
    new ResultCallback<AppInviteInvitationResult>() {

      @Override
      public void onResult(AppInviteInvitationResult result) {

        if (result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {                
          Intent intent = result.getInvitationIntent();
          String deepLink = AppInviteReferral.getDeepLink(intent);
          String invitationId = AppInviteReferral.getInvitationId(intent);     
          if (mAppInviteInvitationResultListener != null) mAppInviteInvitationResultListener.onSuccess(deepLink, invitationId); 
        }
        else {              
          if (mAppInviteInvitationResultListener != null) mAppInviteInvitationResultListener.onError(2, 0);  
        }

        mGoogleApiClient.unregisterConnectionCallbacks(InvitationResult);
        mGoogleApiClient.unregisterConnectionFailedListener(InvitationResult);
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();

      }

    });
```

to use now `FirebaseAppInvite.getInvitation(...) ?`

Answer (score 3):

Please read "handle Deep link " block on the following link:-
https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/android/receive

It has a below method which you can use to convert your code

```
FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance()
        .getDynamicLink(getIntent())
        .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<PendingDynamicLinkData>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(PendingDynamicLinkData pendingDynamicLinkData) {
                // Get deep link from result (may be null if no link is found)
                Uri deepLink = null;
                if (pendingDynamicLinkData != null) {
                    deepLink = pendingDynamicLinkData.getLink();
                }


                // Handle the deep link. For example, open the linked
                // content, or apply promotional credit to the user's
                // account.
                // ...

                // ...
            }
        })
        .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.w(TAG, "getDynamicLink:onFailure", e);
            }
        });
```

I hope it answers your question. Let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: Use this method but didn't receive data